# App is crashing with Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6 in citrus pay integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, objective-c-2.0, citrus-pay

I am using citrus pay payment gateway  for my app and I am using cocoapods to integrate and I am following the below link to integrate.https://github.com/citruspay/citruspay-ios-sdk

```
and the pod file is 
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'Lektrify CEM' do

 pod 'CitrusPay', '~> 4.1.5'

  end
```

the app is crashing showing below error in log.
dyld: Symbol not found: __swiftEmptyDictionaryStorage
  Referenced from: /Users/skumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EEE6ADA-B880-4BBB-9E1D-8E8608D713F2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/415005F9-01B7-40EC-A097-59514558A75E/Lektrify CEM.app/Frameworks/CitrusPay.framework/CitrusPay
  Expected in: /Users/skumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EEE6ADA-B880-4BBB-9E1D-8E8608D713F2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/415005F9-01B7-40EC-A097-59514558A75E/Lektrify CEM.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /Users/skumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7EEE6ADA-B880-4BBB-9E1D-8E8608D713F2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/415005F9-01B7-40EC-A097-59514558A75E/Lektrify CEM.app/Frameworks/CitrusPay.framework/CitrusPay
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6

can so one please help me to solve this problem . thanks for quick responce.